# MySQL update table with null but get warnings

Tags: mysql, null

I use query as below to update table:

```
UPDATE table SET  c1=NULL WHERE c1=2 and Name REGEXP "ABC";
```

But after the query, I get:

```
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 18 warnings (0,00 sec)
```

And the warnings are like below:

```
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N  ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N  ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N  ' |
...
```

Though it seems the 'NULL' value is correctly updated in the table, but then why is the warning? Dose it matters? And how to get rid of these warning?

The version I use is: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 (Ubuntu).

The definition of the column is as below. And there are 6 lines changed, but get 18 warnings:

```
mysql> describe table;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
...
| c1              | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

An update on this issue: for some reason, the warning info is gone when I run the same query some days later.

Comment: May be your `c1` field is `NOT NULL` in nature.

Comment: Are you sure you gave c1=NULL and not c1='NULL'??

Comment: can you provide the structure of the table ?

Comment: @1000111, Vipin, I updated the definition of the table, and the c1 field can be NULL.

Comment: @Akhil, I do use c1=NULL.

Comment: @zhihong Which version of mysql do you use?

Comment: @Akhil, I updated the version in my post. And today when I run the same query in the table, the warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This message means you're trying to compare a number and a string in a WHERE or ON clause. Try turning off strict mode

As the warning count is 18, so what I can predict is it is making comparison for 18 records or 18 times.